# com.googlecode.jdeltasync.UnrecognizedErrorCodeException: 3206: User has maxed out their sync relationship quota

Tags: java, imap, hotmail

i've got an issue with jdelta sync http://code.google.com/p/jdeltasync/.
I'll try to explain.
On the google code web site there is an example of code to use the jdeltasync librairy:

*The following Java code downloads all messages in the Inbox folder to the current directory:*

```
  DeltaSyncClientHelper client = new DeltaSyncClientHelper(
    new DeltaSyncClient(), "example@hotmail.com", "secret");
    client.login();
    Message[] messages = client.getMessages(client.getInbox());
    System.out.println(messages.length + " messages in Inbox");
    for (Message message : messages) {
        File file = new File(message.getId() + ".msg");
        System.out.println("Downloading message from \"" 
            + message.getFrom() + "\" with subject \"" 
            + message.getSubject() + "\" received at " 
            + message.getDateReceived());
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        client.downloadMessageContent(message, out);
        out.close();
    }
```

i've used it successfully but if i used it a second time i've got an "unrecognize error":
***com.googlecode.jdeltasync.UnrecognizedErrorCodeException: 3206: User has maxed out their sync relationship quota***
So my question is anybody already have this problem and does he/she fix it.
Thanks for your time.
Simon

Answer (score 1):

Per my observation hotmail-server accepting max 50 hits in a row and then it is throwing this error and after 10hrs hotmail-server releasing the user to access the account for next 50 hits.
Better try to connect for each 15 mins from your account so that you won't get this error

Answer (score 0):

It's a error from hotmail-server, not from your code. Check this [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/0x8de00002-error-3206-server-user-has-maxed-out/664613f7-38a4-4d24-923a-0712af161da4?msgId=a8a3e431-f678-42fb-9bc7-a3766d3911e8) with similar case.
Switch to different server for testing or try to resolve problem with hotmail.